# Bootable partition

Tags: command-line, live-usb

I usually create a bootable live image of a CD on USB devices with this command:

`sudo dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdx`

The problem is that after using this command, I cannot copy additional files on the device without formatting it. This command uses all space of the usb device.

I want to create a live image on `sdx1` and to use `sdx2` for file storage.

I want a command, not a tool like UNetbootin (it does not work properly, giving me an error for not finding menu.c32 file).

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I need a command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the partition, your just using the entire device, so dd is erasing the entire device. To specify a partition, you need to use the little number at the end of the device name: /dev/sbd1 or whatever number it is. Make sure that partition is bootable using gparted, and selecting boot from the "manage flags" option. (Right click the device partition)

Comment: I created 2 ext4 partitions. I made /dev/sdx1 bootable. I used command `sudo dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdx1` . I made sure sdx1 is bootable. But when I tried to boot it did not work.

Comment: Formatting to fat32 does not work either.